# I need to integrate ckeditor5 with comments in my applications in angularjs. I nowhere find any plugin in angularjs, always I found in angular(2+)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ckeditor4.x, ckeditor5

```
import Comments from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-comments/src/comments';


ClassicEditor.builtinPlugins = [ Essentials, Paragraph, Bold, Italic, Image, Comments ];
```

How can I include comments in `ckeditor5` in `angular js` above code is in `angular 2+`, and I found binding is not happening in ckeditor5 previously I used ckeditor4 and it works perfectly with angular js

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you googled in advance?

https://github.com/lemonde/angular-ckeditor

https://github.com/miamarti/ng.ckeditor

Not sure if they use 5.x version of ckeditor, but at least there are examples of integration

Plus tonnes of examples on different sandbox platforms, and some articles (like https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ru&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fhabr.com%2Fru%2Fpost%2F200058%2F )